# refer EditText as String

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I built a simple app which contains one method,this app should check if the phone number which inserted by the user is valid.
so i did the the following steps:

1. Declar the edit text in the java file
2. Refer the variable to the variable in the xml file
3. Do get text and to string to this variable
4. Write the methoud that refer to the "phone" variable

declare(step 1):

```
private static EditText phone_et_c
```

refare(step 2):

```
phone_et_c=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_et_c);
```

get text and to string(step 3):

```
String phone=phone_et_c.getText().toString();
```

and the mathoud is(step 4):

```
public static boolean isValid(String phone)
{
    if ((phone.length()==10)||(phone.charAt(0)==0&&phone.charAt(1)==5)){
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

my error was that:

> 10-14 10:06:05.885 5140-5140/com.miara.yagel.maspera E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.miara.yagel.maspera, PID: 5140
>                                                                              java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
>                                                                                  at java.lang.String.charAt(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at com.miara.yagel.maspera.CreatUserActivity.isValid(CreatUserActivity.java:69)
>                                                                                  at com.miara.yagel.maspera.CreatUserActivity$1.onClick(CreatUserActivity.java:56)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

thanks!

Comment: somehow the length of my insert is always 0

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that your EditText has a length of 0. So when you convert it to String your String has a length of 0 as well. So indexOf(0) throws an Exception because your String is empty. Use a method like isEmpty() to first check if its empty and then iterate About Indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Change your validation method so that it checks for empty values and if necessary trim the text:

```
public static boolean isValid(String phone) {
    String str = phone.trim();
    int len = str.length();
    return ((len > 0) && ((len == 10)||(str.charAt(0) == 0 && str.charAt(1) == 5)));
}
```

Comment: the problem is even when I put a real number (like 0545845652) its return thats the input is empty... i tried to do trim(), dont work..

Answer (score 0):

i searched in other naswer and found that:
[EditText getText() returns empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066189/edittext-gettext-returns-empty-string)

appear to be that i should write step 3 inside the Onclick buttom.
i know junior mistakes my bad, thank you all