# Why is no data sent to the database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Writing the following code on Android:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference root = db.getReference().child("Users");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText name = findViewById(R.id.nameField);
        EditText age = findViewById(R.id.ageField);
        EditText height = findViewById(R.id.heightField);
        EditText telephone = findViewById(R.id.campoTelephone);

        String nameIntoString = name.getText().toString().trim();
        String ageIntoString = age.getText().toString().trim();
        String heightIntoString = height.getText().toString().trim();
        String telephoneIntoString = telephone.getText().toString().trim();

        Button send = findViewById(R.id.btnSend);

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                HashMap<String, String> enviarParaOBancoDeDados = new HashMap<>();
                enviarParaOBancoDeDados.put("NameIntoString", nameIntoString);
                enviarParaOBancoDeDados.put("ageintoString", ageIntoString);
                enviarParaOBancoDeDados.put("heightIntoString", heightIntoString);
                enviarParaOBancoDeDados.put("telephoneIntoString", telephoneIntoString);

                try {
                    root.push().setValue(enviarParaOBancoDeDados);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully data sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And after trying to send the data to Firebase Database, you can see that the sent values ​​don't appear:

[image]

Why please?

How to fix so that Firebase Database can receive the values ​​that were sent?

Comment: Can you try moving all the `getText()` statements inside the button click listener?

Comment: Thank you. I did what you wrote, but it continues happening the same problem.

Comment: In that case, can you update the question with the updated code and also try logging those values right before the hashmap? Also checkout: [Edittext getText returns empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066189/edittext-gettext-returns-empty-string/21066237)

Comment: Thank you. All the getText() statements must be inside onClick method.
It was solved.